# Problems providing a motivation for solving matrix equations (i.e. equations in which the unknown is not the input vector, but the matrix of the LT).

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, soft-question, systems-of-equations

[L.T. abbreviates " linear transformation"]

---

I can see basic mathematical problems that can be translated into vector equations ( by which I mean  equations  in which the solution set is a set of vectors).

For example, the problem :

$$\text{at what point P=(x,y) do line 1 :}  2x+y=7 $$

$$\text{ and  line 2 :} 7x-3y=10 \space \space \text{meet ?}$$

can be reformulated  as :

$$\begin{pmatrix}2 & 1\\\ 7 & -3\end{pmatrix} X = \begin{pmatrix}7\\\ 10\end{pmatrix} $$

where the unknown $X = \begin{pmatrix}x\\\ y\end{pmatrix}= \vec{P}$.

The problem could also be rephrased as : which input $X$ is mapped by the linear transformation defined by the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}2 & 1\\\ 7 & -3\end{pmatrix}$ to the vector $\begin{pmatrix}7\\\ 10\end{pmatrix}$.

This provides a motivation for solving what I've called " vector equations".

My question is : what if the unknown is not the input, nor the output, but the linear transformation, that is, the matrix itself?

> Are there basic and ( as much as possible) concrete problems in mathematics or in physics that could be
> translated into , so to say, matrix equations ( i.e. equations in which the
> unknown is the matrix tself) and that would provide a motivation for
> solving such equations?

Comment: If the unknown matrix is n by n, then you will need n distinct vector problems to solve for the matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily find a matrix in that case. Consider the following example.

Example: Find a matrix $A$ such that $v=\begin{bmatrix} 3 \\ 7 \\6\end{bmatrix}$ gets mapped to $\begin{bmatrix} 18 \\ 12\\7\end{bmatrix}$.

Recall that $\begin{bmatrix} A_{1,1} &\cdots & A_{1,n}\ \\ \vdots & \\ A_{m,1}&\cdots & A_{m,n}\end{bmatrix}$ $\begin{bmatrix}a_1 \\ \vdots \\a_n \end{bmatrix}=a_1\begin{bmatrix}A_{1,1} \\ \vdots \\ A_{m,1}\end{bmatrix}+\dots +a_n\begin{bmatrix}A_{1,n}\\ \vdots \\ A_{m,n} \end{bmatrix}$.

So we just let the matrix $A=\begin{bmatrix}6&0&0\\0&\frac {12} 7\ & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \frac 7 6\end{bmatrix}$.

You can easily check that $Av=\begin{bmatrix}6&0&0\\0&\frac {12} 7\ & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \frac 7 6\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 3 \\ 7 \\6\end{bmatrix}$=$\begin{bmatrix} 18 \\ 12\\7\end{bmatrix}$

You can also easily construct the linear map that $A$ represents by just picking a basis.